# How to get Matrix using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make matrix like below using numpy

```
matrix_example = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

my Idea is using np.where but It doesn't work well..
I want hint about generate matrix like that.

my second idea is

1. make 9 by 9 matrix fill with zero using `numpy.zeros([9, 9])`
2. change 0 to 1 where index is include 0, 2, 4.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Only that one specific matrix? Then you could probably hardcode it into your script. Or do you plan to have some kind of pattern and a flexible size?

Comment: Yes, I know hardcode is the best way but, I want more smart way to study

Comment: I think I understand your question but it's worded in a very misleading way. from reading your question it reads as if you are trying to convert a list of lists to a matrix, when in fact you are trying to create a very specific matrix (one that has "squares" of 1's and 0's in an alternating pattern). You should probably clarify your question to avoid confusion

Comment: @ExtraFishness I understand what you say. Thanks for your advice. It seems that the question is ambiguous because I am not good at English. I'll be a little more careful next time

Answer (score 0):

```
a2D = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

try this

Comment: Please use code formatting for code

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.ones` and `np.zeros` to do it like:

```py
first_mat = np.ones([9, 9])
second_mat = np.zeros([7, 7])
third_mat = np.ones([5, 5])
forth_mat = np.zeros([3, 3])

first_mat[1:-1, 1:-1] = second_mat
first_mat[2:-2, 2:-2] = third_mat
first_mat[3:-3, 3:-3] = forth_mat
first_mat[4:-4, 4:-4] = 1
```

and this will give you your output, it maybe not the easiest way, but I hope it can help, and of course first_mat is the maxrix you need

Comment: Yes! It does not exactly run but I got a big hints Thanks!

Comment: why doesn't it run? 

Comment: @sudorm-rf oh, I forgot to add the square brackets

Comment: @sudorm-rf not it will give you what you need

Comment: ```import numpy as np
first_mat = np.ones([9, 9])
second_mat = np.zeros([7, 7])
third_mat = np.ones([5, 5])
forth_mat = np.zeros([3, 3])

first_mat[1:-1, 1:-1] = second_mat
first_mat[2:-2, 2:-2] = third_mat
first_mat[3:-3, 3:-3] = forth_mat
first_mat[4:-4, 4:-4] = 1```

Comment: I'm sorry about dirty code block  1. add square brackets  2. change third_matrix to np.ones forth_matrix to np.zeros

Comment: @sudo rm -rf yeah I noticed that and edited it

Answer (score 0):

There's already a `np.matrix` function that makes what you probably want

For you example, it should be as easy as

`my_matrix = np.matrix(matrix_example)`

Have a look at the official documentation for further info :)
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [Mohamed Yahya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16800079/mohamed-yahya)'s answer and generalizing it to any number of "squares":

```
import numpy as np


def cool_matrix(squares):
    final_matrix = np.zeros((squares * 2 - 1, squares * 2 - 1), dtype=np.int)

    for square in range(squares, 0, -1):
        square_dimensions = (square * 2 - 1, square * 2 - 1)
        if square % 2 == 0:
            curr_square = np.zeros(square_dimensions, dtype=np.int)
        else:
            curr_square = np.ones(square_dimensions, dtype=np.int)

        offset = squares + square - 1
        final_matrix[-offset:offset, -offset:offset] = curr_square
    return final_matrix


print(cool_matrix(5))
```

output is:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```